# Alternative to CaptureBAT on Windows 7?

Tags: tools, malware

I am working on some malware that currently only runs with Windows 7 is detected. I would like to use CaptureBAT, but it doesn't work on Windows 7 (with the exception of network monitoring). Is there an alternate to this that will capture deleted files?

I imagine this will need to work at the Kernel leverl for API hooking as well. I have looked at a couple of alternatives including using PowerShell to monitor file changes (http://dereknewton.com/category/powershell/) and also to use the WMI process for logging data, but neither of them are a great solution and I want all captured files that the malware attempts to delete.

Does anyone know of a tool that will work on Windows 7 for this?

Answer (score 1):

[Capture BAT is open-source](https://www.honeynet.org/files/CaptureBAT-Setup-2.0.0-5574-src.zip). Why not just rebuild it for Windows 7?

And based on my 10 seconds of skimming Capture BAT's described functionality, it seems that [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) might be a viable alternative.

Comment: First, I am not a coder so wouldn't know where to begin coding. Second, Process Monitor only observes the system as it runs and dues not capture deleted files of network pcaps

Comment: You don't have to code anything. Just compile it under your own local machine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a kind of hackish method, but works.

Try to run Rohitab API Monitor. This will monitor process creations. If a process is started you will be notified and able to catch its parameter and more :)